# Unable to pass correct component as props to a custom router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to create a `<ProtectedRoute />` component, in which I can pass a component like below

```
<Route exact={true} path={routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
<ProtectedRoute path={routes.HOME} component={Home} authUser={this.state.authUser} />
<ProtectedRoute path={routes.PROJECT} component={Project} authUser={this.state.authUser} />
```

my ProtectedRoute.tsx code

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps {
    path: string;
    component: React.ElementType;
    authUser: any;
}

export class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component<ProtectedRouteProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const Component = this.props.component;
        const authUser = this.props.authUser;
        console.log(this.props.component);

        return authUser ? (
            <Component />
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: routes.LOGIN }} />
            );
    }
}
```

in the props I have tried `React.Component`, `React.ComponentType<any>` too.

However, my app never routes to `Project`, it always routes to `Home`.

So, I added a log to see what I am getting as `this.props.component`.

I always get

```
class Home extends react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.c…
```

which makes me think I am not passing the Component properly.

Can anybody help with the mistake or how to pass a Component using a prop.
PS: If I add `Project` in `Route` instead of `ProtectedRoute`, it works fine.

EDIT: Adding Home/Project Component (Both of them have the same form).

```
export class Project extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Project</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send component

```
<Route exact={true} path={routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
<ProtectedRoute path={routes.HOME} component={()=>(<Home/>)} authUser={this.state.authUser} />
<ProtectedRoute path={routes.PROJECT} component={()=>(<Project/>)} authUser={this.state.authUser} />
```

and the ProtectedRoute

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps {
path: string;
component: React.ElementType;
authUser: any;
}

export class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component<ProtectedRouteProps, {}> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    const authUser = this.props.authUser;
    console.log(this.props.component);

    return authUser ? (
        this.props.component()
    ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: routes.LOGIN }} />
        );
}
```

}

Comment: I get the following error if I do what you have written -> `This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'ElementType<any>' are callable.
    Type '"symbol"' has no call signatures.  TS2349` . I changed the `App.tsx` as you have suggested and kept the return to `<Component />`, that did not work either.

Comment: can you create a minimal codebox with this issue, it's difficult to debug without env

Comment: else you can refer to render prop, which I was referring to or HOC in react